# iPhone app throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS with dictionary from contents of file

Tags: iphone, dictionary, crash, exc-bad-access, nsmutabledictionary

I have the code

```
 NSArray *paths = [[NSArray alloc]   
initWithArray:NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)]; 

NSString *docsDirectory = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[paths objectAtIndex:0]];

NSLog(@"This app's documents directory: %@",docsDirectory);

NSString *docsDirectoryWithPlist = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/Stuff.plist", docsDirectory];



BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docsDirectoryWithPlist isDirectory:NO];

if (fileExists) 
{
    chdir([docsDirectory UTF8String]);
    NSMutableDictionary *readDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Stuff.plist"];
```

in an application's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method and whenever it gets to the last line it crashes, throwing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` along the way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *readDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Stuff.plist"];
```

This line tries to read file from the bundle directory. Read file from full path:

```
NSMutableDictionary *readDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:docsDirectoryWithPlist];
```